# taking screenshot of html content and three js scene

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, screenshot, html2canvas

How can i take and save a screenshot of page which includes all html content and also three js scene? I tried html2canvas but it works only for html elements, and tried this code for taking snapshot of scene :

```
 var saveFile = function(strData, filename) {
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    if (typeof link.download === 'string') {
        document.body.appendChild(link); //Firefox requires the link to be in the body
        link.download = filename;
        link.href = strData;
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link); //remove the link when done
    } else {
        location.replace(uri);
    }
}

var strDownloadMime = "image/octet-stream";

var imgData;

try {
    var strMime = "image/jpeg";
    imgData = core.renderer.domElement.toDataURL(strMime);

    saveFile(imgData.replace(strMime, strDownloadMime), "screenshot.jpg");

} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);
    return;
}
```

both methods work fine separately but I need to take screenshot of whole page with all elements
Do you have any ideas?

Comment: You may want to look at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Screen_Capture_API/Using_Screen_Capture

Comment: ... the security considerations make this more difficult than what the user will need to do in order to just capture his screen with the OS ... you can see the dialog by entering this into the dev tools console ... navigator.mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia() ... a promise is created which is fulfilled after user interaction ... the short answer is you can but it is painful navigating the security concerns.

Comment: The promise then go to filling in another canvas, which does not need to be displayed, and you can read a png image or create a video stream from there.

Answer (score 0):

### ***Please read this post carefully!***

Take a look at this demo, taken from [`threejsfundamentals.org`](https://threejsfunadmentals.org/):

```js
'use strict';

/* global THREE */

function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  function makeInstance(geometry, color, x) {
    const material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({color});

    const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    scene.add(cube);

    cube.position.x = x;

    return cube;
  }

  const cubes = [
    makeInstance(geometry, 0x44aa88,  0),
    makeInstance(geometry, 0x8844aa, -2),
    makeInstance(geometry, 0xaa8844,  2),
  ];

  function resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer) {
    const canvas = renderer.domElement;
    const width = canvas.clientWidth;
    const height = canvas.clientHeight;
    const needResize = canvas.width !== width || canvas.height !== height;
    if (needResize) {
      renderer.setSize(width, height, false);
    }
    return needResize;
  }

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;

    if (resizeRendererToDisplaySize(renderer)) {
      const canvas = renderer.domElement;
      camera.aspect = canvas.clientWidth / canvas.clientHeight;
      camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    }

    cubes.forEach((cube, ndx) => {
      const speed = 1 + ndx * .1;
      const rot = time * speed;
      cube.rotation.x = rot;
      cube.rotation.y = rot;
    });

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(render);

  const elem = document.querySelector('#screenshot');
  elem.addEventListener('click', () => {
    canvas.toBlob((blob) => {
      saveBlob(blob, `screencapture-${canvas.width}x${canvas.height}.png`);
    });
  });

  const saveBlob = (function() {
    const a = document.createElement('a');
    document.body.appendChild(a);
    a.style.display = 'none';
    return function saveData(blob, fileName) {
       const url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
       a.href = url;
       a.download = fileName;
       a.click();
    };
  }());
}

main();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}
#c {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: block;
}
#screenshot {
  position: absolute;
  left: 10px;
  top: 10px;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  cursor: pointer;
}
#screenshot:hover {
  background: #444;
}
#screenshot:focus {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
    <button id="screenshot" type="button">Save...</button>
  <script src="https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r105/three.min.js"></script>
```

**NOTE: The screenshot feature *does not work* in this snippet due to Stack Snippets restrictions, but you can find the working example [`here`](https://r105.threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/lessons/threejs-tips.html), the *SECOND* snippet there**